# i want to get the parent id, only on parent -> child -> child page

Tags: child-pages

here is Hierarchy

Parent (id=34)
  Child
    Child of child-1
    Child of child-2
    Child of child-3
    Child of child-4

I am at child of child, i Just want to show sibblings of child of child if parent is '34', like this

- Child of child-1
- Child of child-2
- Child of child-3
- Child of child-4

I used the below function in function.php, but its not working properly

```
    function is_tree($pid) {      // $pid = The ID of the page we're looking for pages underneath
        global $post;         // load details about this page
        if(is_page()&&($post->post_parent==$pid||is_page($pid)))
               return true;   // we're at the page or at a sub page
        else
               return false;  // we're elsewhere
};
```

Thanks
Furqan Khyraj

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 1):

The page object has 2 properties: post_parent which is the parent page, and ancestors, which is array of all of the page's ancestors in the tree.

```
 $currentPageId = get_the_ID();
 $page = get_page($currentPageId);
 if (in_array(34, $page->ancestors)) {
      $siblings = get_pages(array('child_of' => $page->post_parent));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question that good but check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages.

Will `get_pages( array ( 'child_of' => 34 ) );` help?